# Postgres / hstore : how to get IDs of rows with certain key in their hstore field?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm querying a pgsql DB to find rows that have certain keys in an hstore field:

```
select DISTINCT
from (select id, exist(data, ‘exercise_quiz’) key_exists
  from user_tracking) x
where key_exists = true;
```

It works fine, but I need to print the IDs of the corresponding rows it returns. Can I do this with this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the operator `hstore ? text` [(does hstore contain key?)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

```
select id
from user_tracking
where data ? 'exercise_quiz';
```